# No trailing slash in hostname, HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, asp.net-mvc-2, action-filter

I'm in a bit of a pickle here.

I have an action for which the output is fairly static, until another action is used to update the datasource for the first action. I use HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem to remove that action's cached output so that it is refreshed next time the user loads it.

Basically I have an action like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400, Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return ...
}
```

on my HomeController, and another action on another controller that updates the information used in the former:

```
public ActionResult SaveMenu(int id, Menu menu)
{
    ...
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    ...
}
```

The crazy thing is that this works, as long as you're either loading the URLs `http://site/` or `http://site/Home/Index`. When you use the URL `http://site` it never refreshes.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the way the `OutputCacheAttribute` works, specifically on its dependency on `RouteData` not being null.  The relevant part is:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        new OutputCachedPage(this._cacheSettings).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
 }
```

The `ResultExecutingContext filterContext` derives from `ControllerContext`.  This is the source for `ControllerContext.IsChildAction`:

```
public virtual bool IsChildAction
{
    get
    {
        RouteData routeData = this.RouteData;
        if (routeData == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return routeData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("ParentActionViewContext");
    }
}
```

So, why is this relevant to your question?

Because when you omit the "/" then your `Route` does not match anything.  The default route is "`/`".  An article that explains this more in depth is here: http://www.58bits.com/blog/2008/09/29/ASPNet-MVC-And-Routing-Defaultaspx.aspx .  It was written to explain why the `Default.aspx` file was necessary in ASP.NET MVC 1 projects, but the reason is rooted in the same place.

So, basically, the RouteData is null, so the `OutputCacheAttribute` can't work.  You can solve your problem by doing what Michael Jasper suggested and leveraging URL Rewriting.

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is that since "http://www.mysite.com" does not match any route, it won't be cached?

Comment: Correct...  Unless your use URLRewriting to make it "mysite.com/"

Answer (score 1):

IIS has a very usefull module called URL Rewrite. One of the options is to remove or append a trailing slash to all/specific urls.  If it is simply the trailing slash that is the problem, this should work.

Comment: But wouldn't it be more interesting to understand exactly why it's happening? Perhaps that could lead to a more elegant or comprehensive solution?

Comment: Yes, I do admit my solution is a bit of a broad paint brush.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar behavior in the way SharePoint behaves. SharePoint became confused with `http://site`; it was unable to determine if the URL was to a `File` or a `SharePoint Site`. There's probably something similar going on here.

You've probably resolved the problem by appending the URL with a trailing slash; but, just in case you haven't:

```
url = string.Format( "{0}/", url.TrimEnd( '/' ) );
```